VR Throw Trajectory Prediction in Unity
I'm working on a basketball game and I want to predict the throw so I can determine if the ball will hit a particular target.
I implemented some trajectory logic when a throw occurs and at each interval I'm checking its position.
It works fine when I mock a throw by spawning an object, setting its rigidbody velocity directly then calling my function - All the prediction points line up perfectly with the rigidbody's movement.
The problem I have is when I try doing this in VR - If I throw an object, I expect the XRInteractor would apply the revelant forces to the rigidbody, which I could then evaluate the same way to predict its movement, but the prediction points don't line up.
The predictionStepsList contains a list of positons that I'm then drawing out using Gizmos.DrawSphere.
Is anyone able to explain why the predictions are wrong when in VR but correct if I just mock it outside of VR?
Here's the code I'm using:
    bool PredictTrajectory()
    {
        bool willPassThrough = false;
        Vector3 initialPosition = rb.position;
        Vector3 initialVelocity = rb.velocity;
        Vector3 gravity = Physics.gravity;

        // Loop through each step to predict the position
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            float time = i * 0.1f;
            
            // Calculate predicted position at each time step
            Vector3 predictedPosition = initialPosition + 
                                        initialVelocity * time + 
                                        0.5f * gravity * time * time;
            
            // Assign the predicted position to the LineRenderer to visualize it
            Debug.DrawLine(initialPosition, predictedPosition, Color.green, 2f);
            predictionStepsList.Add(predictedPosition);

            if(predictedPosition.y < 0)
            {
                //We're below the ground so bail
                break;
            }
            
            // Check if this predicted position is within the target range
            if (ScoreHelper.Instance.hoopAttractCollider.bounds.Contains(predictedPosition))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return willPassThrough;
    }


Sussed it. I'm not entirely sure how, but I ended up taking an average of the recent velocities of my throwable and applied them manually to the rb.velocity (plus a bit extra). That seemed to work rather than relying on the XR Interactor to add force to the throwable on release.
